# I am using RaspController to automate irrigation using soil moisture sensor I have problem with configuring custom widget configuration

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4

I have write python codes that detect water moisture and triggers water pump via Raspberry pi 4. I want to display my results on RaspController App on my phone but I still gets error on creating custom widget configuration on Command section to view data as results. has anyone tried to create custom widget using moisture sensor and water pump?

here are the source codes that i have tried

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import socket
import time

sensor_pin = 17
pump_pin = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(pump_pin, GPIO.OUT)

def read_moisture():
    if GPIO.input(sensor_pin) == GPIO.HIGH:
        return "Dry"
    else:
        return "Wet"

def control_pump(status):
    if status == "Dry":
        GPIO.output(pump_pin, GPIO.HIGH)  # Turn ON pump when it's dry
        return "Pump ON"
    else:
        GPIO.output(pump_pin, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn OFF pump when it's wet
        return "Pump OFF"

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 12345))  # Use a port number that is not in use
server_socket.listen(1)
print("Server is waiting for incoming connections...")

try:
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {client_address} established.")

        try:
            while True:
                command = client_socket.recv(1024).decode().strip()

                if command == "get_status":
                    moisture = read_moisture()
                    pump_status = control_pump(moisture)
                    response = f"Soil status: {moisture}\nPump status: {pump_status}"
                    client_socket.send(response.encode())

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            client_socket.close()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server_socket.close()
    GPIO.cleanup()"
```

Comment: What error are you getting and what have you tried to do about?